# How do I get my flask response to show up in the XHR filter?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

What makes a response get filtered by the XHR filter in chrome?

So far I have this code

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def hello_world():
  data = {
      'hello'  : 'world',
      'number' : 3
  }
  js = json.dumps(data)

  resp = Response(js, status=200, mimetype='application/json')

  return resp
```

But if you look at the image below when I add the XHR filter in chrome this request does not get filtered into the XHR request. What would I need to add to the headers?

[image: Not an XHR]

Comment: How are you making the request from the client?

Comment: by going to localhost:5000 and it hits it because it is /